# How do I access my CountDownTimer to cancel it in Java?

Tags: java, android

Making a small game in Android Studio. Basically, the user will have a set amount of time to trigger a button press or the game will end. My CountDownTimer object is inside of a different function than my button click handler. How can I cancel the countDownTimer using cancel() from the button click handler.

Here is my code:

```
public countDownTimer timeLimit;

public void generate() {
    final ProgressBar timer = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.timer);`
        int timeoutSeconds = 5000;
        timer.setMax(timeoutSeconds);
        timeLimit = new CountDownTimer(timeoutSeconds, 100) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                int timeUntilFinished = (int) millisUntilFinished;
                timer.setProgress(timeUntilFinished);
            }

            public void onFinish() {
                gameOver();
            }
        };
        timeLimit.start();
}

public void buttonClicked(View v) {
    timeLimit.cancel();
}
```

I'd be happy to hear any alternative ways to do this as well.

Comment: Declare it as a field variable instead of a local variable.

Comment: Create your timeLimit timer as a class level variable typically known as data member.

Comment: Do you guys have any sample code or documentation on how to do this?

Comment: Declare it outside of the method. Shouldn't need example code, just put the declaration in the field

Comment: Already tried moving it outside of the method with the other variables I have there, but it crashes the app.

Comment: Only move the **declaration** to the field. Leave the initialization where it is.

Comment: @VinceEmigh Moved the blank declaration outside of the method. I can get it to start, but still can't get it to cancel. Can't even get it to cancel via an if statement in the onTick(). Updated the code in my original question to reflect the changes I've tested.

Comment: Did you check to make sure `buttonClick` is even being called? Did you try within `onTick` _without_ an if statement (maybe your condition returned false)? This question has turned into a debugging question, which is off-topic for StackOverflow. You should use a debugger at this point.

Comment: It's working now. Made a typo that Android Studio didn't catch. Thanks for all of the help. If one of you post your solution as an answer instead of a comment, I'll mark you as the solution for this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
The code below works perfectly for me.  

 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private ProgressBar progressBar;
private CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
private Button stopTimerButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    stopTimerButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    stopTimerButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    int timeoutSeconds = 5000;
    progressBar.setMax(timeoutSeconds);
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(timeoutSeconds,100) {
        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            int timeUntilFinished = (int) millisUntilFinished;
            progressBar.setProgress(timeUntilFinished);
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {

        }
    };
    countDownTimer.start();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view == stopTimerButton){
        countDownTimer.cancel();
    }
}
}
```